# Filevault 2 enabled with recovery key linked to Apple ID, can I get the key?

Tags: macos, apple-id, filevault

I enabled FileVault on my Yosemite Mac, and selected the "Allow apple ID to reset password" option.

I paid attention to all the dialogs and though they said to write down my recovery key, it was never shown to me.

Did something go wrong? When I did this years ago with FileVault 1 I was shown the key.

I tested using the Apple ID "change password" function and it seemed to work OK but I'd like to have a copy of the key written down as an extra safety measure.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can still decrypt the drive. I suggest you disable filevault now then enable it again, to get a new code. This time don't save the code to the apple cloud but copy it and email it to yourself.

Comment: Are the two mutually exclusive? If I save to the apple cloud does it mean I can't copy it to text? The dialogs didn't read like that but it seemed to work that way.

Comment: You can still copy the text before you save it to the cloud.

Comment: It wasn't shown to me as I said in the question.